# Retrieving acute accent's instead of comma's from Wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

When I query the global wordpress database, and display them using Handlebars templates, normal comma's are replaced by acute accent's (`) somewhere in the process.

I want to have normal comma's in my result. I tried to change the mysql encoding and using `str_replace()` to replace on the php object, but I wasn't able to do this.

Comment: I have made some formatting changes to your question. Your question is however not answerable until you have added a [MCVE]. Click edit under your question and follow the instructions I left in the comment, then add the MCVE to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have used a simple jQuery function to replace this character. it's called Grave Accent and is replaced like this:

```
  function changeGraveAccent() {
    $('.some-element').each(function(){
      $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\u0060/g, "'"));
    });
  }
```